# Unable to locate element of save button

Tags: selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException,TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\mvintee\project_for_selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("http://pis033/NorthStarWMS/User/PurchaseOrders.aspx?t=1&PO=1")
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(100)
print(driver.title)
driver.find_element("id","Login1_UserName").send_keys("wms")
driver.find_element("id","Login1_Password").send_keys("1")
driver.find_element("class name","rbText").click()
element_to_hover_over=driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="ctl00_MenuTabNew"]/ul/li[4]/span/span')
time.sleep(5)
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="ctl00_MenuTabNew"]/ul/li[4]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element("id","ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ShipOrderGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_btnAdd").click()
element=driver.find_element("id",'btnSave')
time.sleep(5)
element.click()
driver.quit()
```

Nothing happen when i locate element of save button. Rest of the code is working correct. I have tried all most everything but still locators not working.

Comment: can you share url of the page, also share your code

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element along with your code trials.

Comment: @vintee please note that whenever you post your code, please do so in **code format**. Image format is not recommended and is very hard to reproduce and debug.